# How store date in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

I have date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format. How can I store it in a database, if I want to do some operations on it afterwards?

For example, I must find out the rows, where `date > something`. What type I must set for the `date` field?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To store dates or times in MySQL use [`date`, `datetime` or `timestamp`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html). I'd recommend the first two for most purposes.

To tell MySQL how to parse your date format use the [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function. Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (`Date` Date);
INSERT INTO table1 (`Date`) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('01/05/2010', '%m/%d/%Y'));
SELECT * FROM table1;

Date
2010-01-05
```

To format the results back into the original form look at the [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function. Note that you only need to format it if you want to display it as a string using something other than the default format.

Comment: but when i use timestamp, it looks like this 0000-00-00 00:00:00, when i try to save for example 21/05/2010 date

Comment: @Syon: I've updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 3):

Use `date` if you only care about the date and not about the exact time.

Answer (score 1):

or just `date` if you don't need time information

Answer (score 0):

use datetime or time stamp and using format functionL

http://davidwalsh.name/format-date-mysql-date_format

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/article/mysql/format-date-time-mysql/