# set date field with current today date without specifying time in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, sqldatatypes

How to set the default date field with "current today date" ONLY without mentioning time in mysql.

---

### Example:

1. 2016-07-05           ---> what i want (current today)
2. 2016-07-05 18:53:44  ---> not required x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how store date in mysql database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869874/how-store-date-in-mysql-database)  What's the data type in your table?

Comment: if it's a `date` field, then there's no time value stored, period. if it's datetime, then you can choose what to use: `set datefield=curdate(), datetimefield=now()`. curdate() is JUST the date, now() is date+time.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> insert into Table(date) values(now());
Query OK, 1 row affected, 3 warnings (0.06 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys, finally i found the answer.
Date fields can't be set with the current date ONLY, instead we can use datetime or timestamp with default value of current_timestamp to set them with current date in the form of 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'